# Definition of cross section ratio $R$ for $e^+ e^- \to $ hadrons?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, scattering-cross-section

As it is commonly defined {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(cross_section_ratio), the cross section ratio is given by:
$$R = \frac{\sigma(e^+e^-\to \mathrm{hadrons})}{\sigma(e^+ e^- \to \mu^+ \mu^-)} $$
Out of curiosity, why is the denominator chosen to be the cross section of the interaction $e^+ e^- \to \mu^+ \mu^-$ and not $e^+ e^- \to \ell^+ \ell^-$ for $\ell$ as another lepton flavour? Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you write down the tree level diagrams involved? Do the electron and positron *have* to annihilate to a photon in your hypothetical if the product is $e^+e^-$? As for $\tau^+\tau^-$, that lepton was discovered after the popularity of *R* was established, and has a messier decay and detection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- First of all, $e^+ + e^- \to e^+ + e^-$ has a very fundamental problem in that you don't know if a reaction we are interested in happened, or if a simple scattering event occurred instead.
- Secondly muons are experimentally easy. Very, very easy. They are long-lived, highly penetrating, and have distinctive end-states; a combination that makes them about the most easily IDed particle there is.

  Basically, if you can do it with muons it's going to be harder with any other particle.

Comment: Shouldn't you know that something happened by the change in momentum?  Unfortunately, that *something* could involve t-channel exchange of a photon  instead of s-channel annihilation followed by pair (re)creation.

Comment: @BertBarrois Uhm. Yeah. We don't know if *the right* reaction occured.